# ORM and SQL injections

Tags: orm, sql-injection

If i use a ORM (Eg: SQLAlchemy or the one that comes with Django ), does that mean my web application is protected from SQL Injections or i need to take extra precautions for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it has a quoting system like most of ORM's (check the source), so you would probably be safe unless you override it.  It never hurts to take extra precautions, though you're never really 100% safe.